# How to mock associated objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-mocha

I know that I can mock objects as follows:

```
Account.any_instance.expects(:type).returns("premium")
```

I remember hearing that this is considered a poor practice. I'd love to do something like

```
user = users(:bob)
user.account.expects(:type).returns("premium")
```

but this doesn't seem to mock the right object. Is there a better solution than using `any_instance` call on the class?

**Edit**: the error message that I'm getting is

```
not all expectations were satisfied
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Account:0x5f9f8f8>.type(any_parameters)
```

Comment: I think it would be even better if you show the whole method and the whole test. Right now it can only be a matter of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I am still finding my way with mocks but have you tried something like:

```
account = user.account
account.expects(:type).returns("premium")
```

It would help to have the context of your test to know which object you wanted mocked.

Comment: Just tried that, thanks. I'm getting the same error message which I'll add to my question in a bit.